# Сalling the http ServeTLS function with comments in the argument

Tags: http, go

I saw this code.

```
    go func() {
        var err error
        if hasCert(s.TLSConfig) {
            err = s.ServeTLS(ln, "" /*certFile*/, "" /*keyFile*/)
        } else {
            err = s.Serve(ln)
        }
        if err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            errs <- err
        }
    }()
```

The `ServeTLS` is located in net/http. Why are there comments in the arguments? If the ServeTLS function receives certificates from the config, why add it to the arguments.

ServeTLS prototype
`func (srv *Server) ServeTLS(l net.Listener, certFile, keyFile string) error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config

It configures many things for TLS, but not server key and cert.   So it's not actually redundant to specify them to `ServeTLS`